# JQuery : How to combine motion with fadeout

Tags: jquery, fade, slide

I have an image of an arrow which I want, onclick, to move the left say 200px and - while it is moving it should fade to 0 opacity.

So far I have:

```
jQuery.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) {
        return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle', width: 'toggle'}, speed,
easing, callback);
};
```

which kind of works, but it does not move the object it reduces it's width instead. How do I achieve the effect of "motion" with a fade at the same time?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? `$('#myobject').animate({left: '-=200px'}).fadeOut();` They are asynchronous, so just chain them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you change `width` to `left`?

Like this

```
jQuery.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) {
    return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle', left: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback);
};
```

Comment: yes this is the right answer but you need to put a value in left - toggle does not work - you have to specify e.g left : '400px'

Comment: @Ashley; `left: "-=200px"` will do a relative move, as I mentioned in my comment to your question.

Comment: @roe : perfect , just what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/). It ships with a lot of nice effects...